# Retrieve Firebase data using Python

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a doorlock system which will be controlled by an android app. I have installed firebase and given a condition which will change my firebase value from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 according to lock / unlock, 0 for lock and 1 for unlock.

Now I want to retrieve the data from Python and send it to an Ardiuno. I have connected the Ardiuno to the serial port of a Raspberry Pi.

The problem I am facing is that the following Python script is only fetching/retrieving the data stored before in my Firebase, like if I have 0 it is printing 0 continuously. I want to change it every time it changes in Firebase. The Firebase data is changing every time on my button click but the Python script is not getting the updated data.

```
from firebase import firebase
import serial

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://smartdoor-922ad.firebaseio.com/smartdoor-922ad',)
result = firebase.get('smartdoor-922ad', '')
while True:
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to retrieve data again, after it is updated. Right now you're printing the once retrieved data again and again.

```
from firebase import firebase
import serial

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://smartdoor-922ad.firebaseio.com/smartdoor-922ad',)
while True:
  result = firebase.get('smartdoor-922ad', '')
  print(result)
```

While the above script should work. There will be a throttling issue as you're continuously calling the firebase. To solve it, update your code to use Firebase triggers, so that your code will only run when data is updated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Use firebase admin to listen to the changes:

```
import firebase_admin

def listener(event):
    print(event.event_type)  # can be 'put' or 'patch'
    print(event.path)  # relative to the reference, it seems
    print(event.data)  # new data at /reference/event.path. None if deleted

firebase_admin.db.reference('smartdoor-922ad').listen(listener)
```

Comment: could you please write the code in addition to this so i can get every updated value continousely please

Comment: @Muhammad Asif, it is beyond the scope of the current question. I can guide you to the right direction. You will have to use onUpdate trigger.

Comment: sir there is no python code available for firebase triggers please help i have searched each and every website.

Comment: please someone help its urgent it need to complete my project

Comment: @Muhammad Asif, give me some time, I'll do it tonight

Comment: Ok it will be very great full if you could help me solve this issue

Comment: have you done it , if yes please provide it i need the help

Comment: @MuhammadAsif, I have further added code for the update listener.